# Python in DLL (c++) Visual studio

Tags: python, c++, windows, dll-injection

I have visual studio, i try to execute python in GAME by DLL inject.

this is my code:

```
#include "windows.h"
#define MS_NO_COREDLL
#include <Python.h>
#include <detours.h>

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <fcntl.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "detours.lib")
using namespace std;

void pickupitem(){
    PyObject* args = PyTuple_New(0);
    PyObject* ret = PyObject_Call(PyObject_GetAttrString(PyImport_ImportModule("player"), "PickCloseItem"), args, NULL);
    double result = PyFloat_AsDouble(ret);
    Py_DECREF(ret);
    Py_XDECREF(args);
    //return result;
}
BOOL APIENTRY DllMain(HANDLE hModule, DWORD ul_reason_for_call, LPVOID lpReserved)
{
    switch (ul_reason_for_call)
    {
    case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
        pickupitem();
        break;
    case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
        break;
    case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
        break;
    case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
        break;
    }
    return TRUE;
}
```

It compile fine but, my "Winject" (program to inject DLL) got error which say nothing about problem.

When i edit my code and change it to :

```
case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
MessageBoxA(NULL, (LPCSTR) "WORK!", (LPCSTR) "YES !", NULL);
pickupitem();
break;
```

I saw 2x WORK! but winject still return error.

I think this is fault of visual studio compiler , could you tell me whats wrong ?

I have installed python2.7.6 add folder /libs to linker ,and /include to compiler.

It is possible to debug this dll, and know where is the problem?

Best Regards.

Comment: What version of Visual Studio do you have? I know that when writing extensions, the version of VS used to build the extension has to be the same as the version used to compile Python. Not sure if it applies to embedding, though.

Comment: Version 2013 i downloaded too python extension for VS

Answer (score 0):

how about add call to Py_Initialize() and Py_Finalize(), see
http://docs.python.org/2/c-api/init.html

Comment: It crashing program where my dll is injected ;x

Comment: i'm operate on python 2.7.6 and in this game dir i see "python22.dll" i paste there python27.dll but idk that it is included to game. (Game - metin2 ;p)

Comment: anyone know something ?:D

Comment: try run equivalent Python script first.<pre>import player ret=player.PickCloseItem() print ret</pre>

Comment: There maybe some Exceptions/Errors during Python API calls, try break second line in to three lines, and adds some Exception Handling calls between those calls.http://docs.python.org/2/c-api/exceptions.html

Comment: There is a error in this
` PyObject* test = PyObject_GetAttrString(PyImport_ImportModule("player"), "PickCloseItem");`
Bcoz when i comment this line i can inject dll without errors